# Read data from a Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a `Socket` listening on some x port.

I can send the data to the socket from my client app but unable to get any response from the server socket.

```
BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = bis.readLine()) != null)
{
    instr.append(inputLine);      
}
```

This code part reads data from server.

But I can't read anything from server until unless the `Socket` on the server is closed.
Server code is not under my control to edit something on it.

How can I overcome this from client code.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To communicate between a client and a server, a protocol needs to be well defined.

The client code blocks until a line is received from the server, or the socket is closed. You said that you only receive something once the socket is closed. So it probably means that the server doesn't send lines of text ended by an EOL character. The `readLine()` method thus blocks until such a character is found in the stream, or the socket is closed. Don't use readLine() if the server doesn't send lines. Use the method appropriate for the defined protocol (which we don't know).

Comment: Ok I now understand the `readLine()` but is there any standard mechanism to read data fully irespective what server protocol ;)

Comment: Yes, read bytes from the stream until -1 is returned, which indicates that the socket is closed. But what's the point of receiving something if you don't even know what it is?

Comment: I understand the idea of well defined. I have the same problem. On my server I use a BufferedWriter and writeLine() with it and then I flush it. Still I get nothing from readLine() on the buffered input stream. Wouldn't using writeLine() paired with readLine() be considered well defined? I have tried sending communication both ways and nothing is ever received. I have verified that a connection is established.

Comment: @ydobonebi post your own question, with the relevant code needed to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like the server may not be sending newline characters (which is what the `readLine()` is looking for). Try something that does not rely on that. Here's an example that uses the buffer approach:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
pw.println();
pw.flush();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    String output = new String(buffer, 0, read);
    System.out.print(output);
    System.out.flush();
};
clientSocket.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this code is strange:

```
bis.readLine()
```

As I remember, this will try to read into a buffer until he founds a `'\n'`. But what if is never sent?

My ugly version breaks any design pattern and other recommendations, but always works:

```
int bytesExpected = clientSocket.available(); //it is waiting here

int[] buffer = new int[bytesExpected];

int readCount = clientSocket.read(buffer);
```

You should add the verifications for error and interruptions handling too. 
With webservices results this is what worked for me ( 2-10MB was the max result, what I have sent)

Comment: You don't need to call available() at all, and it isn't reliable. Just read into a fixed size buffer. There are very few correct uses of available(), and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @EJP I wrote it isn't correct, and I told it is working, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation

```java
 clientSocket = new Socket(config.serverAddress, config.portNumber);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

  while (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
    data = in.readLine();

    if (data != null) {
        logger.debug("data: {}", data);
    } 
}
```