# Java socket not always getting all bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I have problem with my Java app using sockets. After connecting to socket on server we can download file.

The procedure looks like this:

- client send message to server with file name to download
- server responds with file size
- then server sends to socket all file bytes

Here's my Java code:

```
//init keyManagerFactory and trustManager
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(new Socket(ipAddress, port), ipAddress, port, false);
socket.startHandshake();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
... 

int toRead = xxxx; //received from server response
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
while(toRead > 0) {
    byte b = in.readByte();
    bytes.add(b);
    toRead--;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I get all bytes from server but other times I get only part of it and there's no more data, e.g. server sends file size = 1500, my app is trying to get it from socket but there's only 1100 bytes, other time there's 1200, and some other time 1500.

You could say - It's a server issue. But I've written program in Python with the same functionality and it always works ok!

Here's python code:

```
def recv(sock, toread):
    buf = bytearray(toread)
    view = memoryview(buf)
    while toread:
        nbytes = sock.recv_into(view, toread)
        if nbytes == 0:
            sock.close()
            raise Disconnected
        view = view[nbytes:]
        toread -= nbytes
    return buf

plainsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(plainsock, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
sock.connect(someIP, somePort)

...

toRead = xxxx //received from server response

data = recv(sock, toRead)
```

I don't have much experience with Sockets in Java. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: TCP, UDP? You have to wait until all data arrives, the underlying OS can split the data however it see fits.

Comment: rather than reading x amount of bytes, just read til the end of the stream `is.read == -1`

Comment: @ScaryWombat could you give some code snippet how to do that?

Comment: @vz0 it's TCP connection

Comment: Nah, but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608878/read-data-from-a-java-socket

Comment: Is that a custom protocol? It is strange that you would do two requests for that where one would be enough...

Comment: @fge what do you mean by two requests? My side (client) sends one message with requested file.

Comment: Can you show socket instantiation?

Comment: @degr I've edited my post and included socket instantiation