# How to get server's SSH version without authenticating in JSch?

Tags: java, networking, ssh, jsch

I tried to use JSch:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    var session = new JSch().getSession("host");
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    var version = session.getServerVersion();
    System.out.println("version = " + version);
}
```

but I'm getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "str" is null

It seems that this implementation requires you to connect and authenticate.

How can I get this information with Java, without the need to authenticate?

---

This Python code works for me on a server that requires authentication yet I didn't have to authenticate in order to get the remote version.

```py
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.Transport(("host", 22))
ssh.start_client()
print(ssh.remote_version)
ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH identification string is sent in *plain text* right after opening the connection.

So you do not need an SSH library to obtain the string.

You can do with a simple code like shown here:
[Read Data from a Java Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16608878/850848)

---

Or just try to login using dummy credentials with JSch and then read `Session.getServerVersion`.

You do not even have to try to login. You can abort the connection right at the host key check:

```
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
```

Comment: you're right, I was able to getServerVersion from within the catch clause!